# Мультиязычность в bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Планирую добавить на сайт второй язык.
Как делаются переключатели языковые и как делается перевод на второй язык статичной информации на сайте?

Comment: @Nikolaj Sarry извиняюсь, я наверное не совсем правильно поставил вопрос. Я имел ввиду сам механизм кнопок, например когда щелкнули на кнопку English, то механизм который ведет на english версию сайта, как он реализовывается примерно. Просто сейчас я вообще понятия не имею как это сделать ). Я хотел сдвинутся с места =). Не обижайтесь ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в чем-то правы, Dolphin.

Начинайте работать сейчас. Добавляйте второй язык на сайт. Добавляйте Язык в массив $[MESS] из примера.

```
$MESS["ERROR_HTTP_READ"] = "Ошибка чтения HTTP данных.";
$MESS["ERROR_UNKNOWN_COMMAND"] = "Неизвестная команда.";


function GetMessage_($name,$aReplace=null){ 
    global $MESS;
    if (isset($MESS[$name]))
    {
        $s = $MESS[$name];

        if ($aReplace !== null && is_array($aReplace))
        {
            foreach($aReplace as $search => $replace)
            {
                $s = str_replace($search, $replace, $s);
            }
        }

        return $s;
    }   
}

/*
Этот код можно запустить или выполнить в VSCode 
*/

print_r(GetMessage_("ERROR_HTTP_READ"));
```

После того, как написали свой языковой файл (для компоненты, для шаблона компоненты), вы сможете переключить язык не для всего сайта, а только для одной страницы примерно так

```
$context = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getInstance()->getContext();

/* Текущий язык $langId */
$langId = $context->getLanguage();

/* На какой переключаем */
\Bitrix\Main\Localization\Loc::setCurrentLang("en");


/* Чтобы проверить, подключился ли ваш файл, в шаблоне компоненты напишите 
echo "<pre>GetMessage:"; print_r (GetMessage('FORM_DATA_SAVED1')); echo "</pre>";
или задайте вопрос "Как подключить свой языковой шаблон"
*/

$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:form.result.new",
        "inline",
        Array(
```

Потом уже, чуть позже, не забудьте погуглить вопрос **psr-0 vs psr-4**, и через три недели сможете сами подключать языковые файлы и библиотеки. А пока просто пишите перевод языка в массив $[MESS]

Comment: А еще лучше прочитать про языковые файлы в битриксе в документации. Статичную информацию храните в инфоблоках, и в зависимости от языка подключайте/выводите нужный инфоблок. Лэнг-файлы в компонентах уже есть так что тут вообще не будет проблемы.

Comment: @Blay Wille мне не совсем понятно как показать перевод из языкового файла, например если пользователь нажал на второй язык, далее маханизм который покажет перевод статической информации, например меню в header? Прошу учесть то что для вас сейчас легко, для меня это сложновато понимается, так как у нас с вами уровни знаний разные).

Comment: задача по смене языка для отдельной страницы -  определить константу LANGUAGE_ID LANG_ADMIN_LID прежде чем это сделает битрикс, это делается, как вариант, в dbcon.php А вообще пример переключения константы LANG_ADMIN_LID есть в админке битрикс. Ответ подправил и привел пример

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте во вкладках сайты-шаблоны условия включения одного или другого шаблона